# Regex.IsMatch for postcode

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regex which can satisfy all my three conditions for zip-code:

1. can be length 10
2. can't numbers 0 or 2
3. in index [5] cant 5

Comment: This doesn't look like a difficult pattern. There are also a *lot* of regex libraries, sites etc online, a google search would probably return exactly what you want, eg: `regex somecountry zip code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[13-9]{4}[1346-9][13-9]{5}$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/12